# How to match the objects with a model object and create the missing properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to match an object with a model object to give the shape of the object the same as a model object. for example
**the model object is this**

```
{
  bg:{padding:0,fontSize:0},
  label:{padding:0, bg:''},
  font:{fontSize:0}
}
```

here are the other objects for examples

```
{
  bg:{padding:5},
  label:{ bg:'something'},
}
```

So when we match  the below object with model one the below one should be like this

```
 {
  bg:{padding:5,fontSize:0},
  label:{padding:0, bg:'something'},
  font:{fontSize:0}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `for..in` on your object and merge both data:

```js
const obj= {
  bg:{padding:0,fontSize:0},
  label:{padding:0, bg:''},
  font:{fontSize:0}
};

const newObj={
  bg:{padding:5},
  label:{ bg:'something'},
};


const getNewObj=(previous,current)=>{
   for(let o in previous){
    previous[o]={...previous[o], ...current[o]}
};
return previous;
};

console.log(getNewObj(obj, newObj))
```

Comment: but its pamking wrong object when comes any array in object e.g bg:['something']

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries()` and then `Array.prototype.reduce()`. 
Get the `key` and spread the values of the first object and the second object like so:

```js
const obj = {
  bg:{padding:0,fontSize:0},
  label:{padding:0, bg:''},
  font:{fontSize:0}
}

const obj2 = {
  bg:{padding: 5},
  label:{ bg:'something'},
}

const res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[key] = {
    ...value,
    ...obj2[key]
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```